# Analytic funnelling, tracking two URLs with different parameters, both being triggered as the same URL.

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics

I want to be able to track goals but I need to know whether they came from a page with a social media parameter or a digital marketing parameter in the URL.

I currently have subscription form which returns a URL with a specific parameter depending on which page we're on. We're using wordpress.

```
<?php if(is_page( 'internet-marketing-software')): ?>
<div class="free-trial" style="display:none;">
    <div class="sign-up-button" style="/* display:none; */">
        <form name="signup" id="signup" action="http://dmtrk.net/signup.ashx" method="post" onsubmit="return validate_signup(this)">
            <input type="hidden" name="addressbookid" value="1922561">
            <input type="hidden" name="userid" value="52978">
            <input type="hidden" name="ReturnURL" value="http://test-site.com/?signup=false&amp;step2=true&amp;digital-marketing=true&amp;form=form-banner">
            <input id="input" type="text" name="Email" placeholder="name@email.com">
            <input type="hidden" id="double" name="double" value="double">
            <input id="submit" class="banner" type="Submit" name="Submit" value="sign up">
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class='trial-desc'>
        <p>Interested? <span>Start 30 day FREE trial now!</span>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I load a similar piece of code in the header this time with the condition

`if(is_page( 'social-media'))`

and which returns the url

`http://test-site.com/?signup=false&amp;step2=true&amp;social-media=true&amp;form=form-banner`.

I so depending on the page each user gets taken to either the social-media or digital-marketing page.

When this URL us triggered a double opt-in email is sent with a link taking them to the true goal page `http://test-site.com/?signup=true`.

**In Google Analytics I have set up two goals with the funnelling capability turned on.**

I currently have the **destination** setup as:

```
RegEx        /?signup=true
Funnelling   On
Step         &digital-marketing=true
```

And then for social:

```
RegEx        /?signup=true
Funnelling   On
Step         &social-media=true
```

Looking at my reports each time a goal is triggered, no matter which URL was used they both register as a goal.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, is there something I'm overlooking with Analytics and URL parameters?

Comment: Steps are only for funnel visualization. Destination goals are tracked only by url. If you have two destination goals with the same url they will always both be triggered, not matter what you enteres as funnel steps.

Comment: I guess the question would be a better fit for the webmasters site since it is about configuration, not programming.

Comment: @EikePierstorff ah, so it doesn't work as a condition then? Like only register this goal if step1 has been completed?

Answer (score 0):

To follow up on the comments (I cannot comment) - You should mark the previous page (coming from digital marketing or social) as "required step" to make sure that the goal will register in one of the paths, and not both. See the button on the right. 
[image]

Comment: Thanks, yes, I missed that in my question but I already had that option set. Is it true though that it's only for visualisation and not as a condition for tracking goals?

Comment: True, it applies only to the funnel visualization. If you want to different goals then the goal destination should be different. You can also do it with a goal destination URL that includes a dummy parameter (such as &funnel=social).